# How do I fix "IntelliSense was unable to determine accurate completion list for this expression" message in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

I'd like to use Visual Studio to do some JS coding but I'm not sure how to fix IS to get the types of variables correctly.

I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xg3Mc.png) message even though I've added all required references. The `$gameMessage` is declared in `rpg_managers.js` file.

My guess is that it's due to the fact that upon declaration, there's `null` assigned to the variable ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdOoz.png)). How do I fix it without interfering in the `rpg_managers.js` file? Unfortunately, it's not as easy as C#, since there's no hard-coded types in JS.

Can I fix this easily, or should I use some other IDE for js? Because I think I saw once someone using some other editor and this problem didn't occur.